# create csv headers from log file python

Tags: python, pandas, csv

My log file contains some info in every row like below

```
Info1:NewOrder|key:123 |Info3:10|Info5:abc
Info3:10|Info1:OldOrder| key:456| Info6:xyz
Info1:NewOrder|key:007
```

I want to change it to a csv like below (if i give key,Info1,Info3 as required headers)

```
key,Info1.Info3
123,NewOrder,10
456,OldOrder,10
007,NewOrder,
```

Earlier I used awk to get field values, but logging can change the order of info and key printed in a row. So I cannot be sure that Info3 would always be in some particular column. Everytime,logging changes, the script needed to be changed.

I intend then to load csv in pandas dataframe. So a python solution would be better. This is more of a data cleaning task to generate a csv from logfile.

This is what I have used after reading the answers

```
import csv
import sys
with open(sys.argv[1], 'r') as myLogfile:
        log=myLogfile.read().replace('\n', '')

requested_columns = ["OrderID", "TimeStamp", "ErrorCode"]

def wrangle(string, requested_columns):
        data = [dict([element.strip().split(":") for element in row.split("|")]) for row in string.split("\n")]
        body = [[row.get(column) for column in requested_columns] for row in data]
        return [requested_columns] + body

outpath = sys.argv[2]
open(outpath, "w", newline = "") with open(outpath, 'wb')
        writer = csv.writer(file)
        writer.writerows(wrangle(log, requested_columns))
```

Sample logfile=https://ideone.com/cny805

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use a csv reader with a `|` delimiter to get you started, then split using `:` to give you a per row dictionary as follows:

```
import csv

with open('input.csv', 'rb') as f_input, open('output.csv', 'wb') as f_output:
    csv_output = csv.writer(f_output)
    cols = ["OrderID", "TimeStamp", "ErrorCode"]
    csv_output.writerow(cols)

    for row in csv.reader(f_input, delimiter='|'):
        # Remove any entries that do not have a colon
        row = [c for c in row if c.find(':') != -1]
        # Convert remaining columns into a dictionary
        entries = {c.split(':')[0].strip() : c.split(':')[1].strip() for c in row}
        csv_output.writerow([entries.get(c, "") for c in cols])
```

Giving you an output file:

```
OrderID,TimeStamp,ErrorCode
3000000,1488948188555841641,
3000000,1488948188556444675,0
```

---

To read the data directly into a Pandas dataframe:

```
import pandas as pd
import csv

cols = ["OrderID", "TimeStamp", "ErrorCode"]
data = []

with open('input.csv', 'rb') as f_input:
    csv_output = csv.writer(f_output)

    for row in csv.reader(f_input, delimiter='|'):
        # Remove any entries that do not have a colon
        row = [c for c in row if c.find(':') != -1]
        # Convert remaining columns into a dictionary
        entries = {c.split(':')[0].strip() : c.split(':')[1].strip() for c in row}
        data.append([entries.get(c, "") for c in cols])

df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=cols)
print df
```

Giving you:

```
   OrderID            TimeStamp ErrorCode
0  3000000  1488948188555841641          
1  3000000  1488948188556444675         0
```

Comment: thanks but im getting `TypeError: argument 1 must be an iterator`

Comment: Which version of Python are you using? Also on what line did you get the error?  I have tested this in Python 2.7.6 and Python 3.5.2.

Comment: Python 2.7.5 sample logfile with 2 lines (sign is : and not = ): https://ideone.com/cny805 columns required can be OrderID,Timestamp,ErrorCode

Comment: That data format needed a slightly different approach. I have updated the script accordingly.

Comment: Works like a charm, I would work on understanding how dict is created (entries). Dont know what it will take to reach your level. Big thanks

Comment: You are welcome. The dict is created using a "dictionary comprehension" which is a relatively new Python feature. Don't forget to click the grey tick under the up/down arrows to accept the solution.

Comment: How do I load this into pandas dataframe, in case I dont want to write a csv, I tried `df=pd.DataFrame(([entries.get(c, "") for c in cols]))` but it gives me only 1 column

Comment: You would need to build a list of rows and then pass that in one go. I have added an example.

Answer (score 0):

The bulk of it is just using useful string methods like strip and split, plus list comprehensions.

```
import csv

string = """Info1=NewOrder|key=123 |Info3=10|Info5=abc
Info3=10|Info1=OldOrder| key=456| Info6=xyz
Info1=NewOrder|key=007"""

requested_columns = ["key", "Info1", "Info3"]

def wrangle(string, requested_columns):
    data = [dict([element.strip().split("=") for element in row.split("|")]) for row in string.split("\n")]
    body = [[row.get(column) for column in requested_columns] for row in data]
    return [requested_columns] + body

outpath = "whatever.csv"

with open(outpath, "w", newline = "") as file:
    writer = csv.writer(file)
    writer.writerows(wrangle(string, requested_columns))
```

Comment: thanks @Denziloe, could you please elaborate wrangle method. Still a learner I am.

Comment: No problem. It uses something called comprehensions. You can learn about them here: https://docs.python.org/3.6/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions. You should also try putting print statements inside wrangle to print data and body, which will show you quite clearly how they are working. If the code works please approve the answer. ; )

Comment: TypeError: 'newline' is an invalid keyword argument for this function `  File "<stdin>", line 3, in <module>
  File "<stdin>", line 2, in wrangle
ValueError: dictionary update sequence element #0 has length 3; 2 is required
`

Comment: Are you using Python 2? It should work for Python 3. In Python 2 I think you should replace open(outpath, "w", newline = "") with open(outpath, 'wb'). Read the documentation for csv if this still doesn't work. In any case the wrangle function should work.

Comment: I also tried replacing \n while reading from input file, to be read into a variable, sample logfile  is at ideone.com/cny805

Comment: Why would you replace newlines? The string in my example uses newlines.

Comment: But still it does not work (even without removing newlines aswell) I just tried if that was a problem

Comment: You are trying to run exactly the code I posted, and you have changed open like I said? What error are you getting now?