# Use particular column value as key to search in pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I need to get rows with particular column value as key
Below is my pandas df.

```
>>> data
     OrderID            TimeStamp  ErrorCode Duration          ResponseType  \
0    3000000  1488948188555841641        NaN      IOC                   NaN   
1    3000000  1488948188556444675          0      NaN     NEW_ORDER_CONFIRM   
2    3000000  1488948188556448153          2      NaN         TRADE_CONFIRM   
3    3000001  1488948658787676012        NaN      IOC                   NaN   
4    3000001  1488948658787811582          1      NaN     NEW_ORDER_CONFIRM   
5    3000001  1488948658787824862          2      NaN         TRADE_CONFIRM   
6    3000002  1488949064945887091        NaN      IOC                   NaN   
7    3000003  1488949109654115659        NaN      IOC                   NaN   
8    3000003  1488949109654294973          1      NaN     NEW_ORDER_CONFIRM   
9    3000003  1488949109654299930      16388      NaN  CANCEL_ORDER_CONFIRM
```

I need to select all orderID where Duration is IOC (fairly easy)
used as given in answer `orders = data.loc[data.Duration == 'IOC', 'OrderID'].unique()` and then get the rows for those selected OrderID where duration is NaN. OrderID will always be in 3 or just a single ORDERID (for which no output or null row can be returned, like in case of OrderID 3000002)

The tricky part is that Errorcode in NEW_ORDER_CONFIRM is correct and the one in TRADE_CONFIRM or CANCEL_ORDER_CONFIRM are WRONG. I just want those correct values in my final row outputs.

```
EXPECTED O/P ROW 1 
     OrderID            TimeStamp  ErrorCode Duration          ResponseType  \
0    3000000  1488948188555841641        0      IOC                   TRADE_CONFIRM
```

I tried using bash by using `grep IOC loglife| cut -d, -f1 to get OrderID then grep each OrderID & NaN`. But I need a python solution which would be much more efficient

Answer (score 0):

I think you can first get all [`unique`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.unique.html) values of column `OrderID` where is `IOC` in `Duration` and then select all `NaN` by [`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#boolean-indexing) - mask is created by [`isin`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.isin.html) with [`isnull`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.isnull.html):

```
#unique can be omit, but then solution a bit slowier in big df 
orders = df.loc[df.Duration == 'IOC', 'OrderID'].unique()

df = df[df.OrderID.isin(orders) & df.Duration.isnull()]
print (df)
   OrderID            TimeStamp  ErrorCode Duration          ResponseType
1  3000000  1488948188556448153        2.0      NaN         TRADE_CONFIRM
3  3000001  1488948658787824862        2.0      NaN         TRADE_CONFIRM
6  3000003  1488949109654299930    16388.0      NaN  CANCEL_ORDER_CONFIRM
```

Comment: Thanks can you also tell me how to read data into dataframe rather than write csv (last comment in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42669216/create-csv-headers-from-log-file-python/42670850?noredirect=1#comment72473336_42670850 question)

Comment: I try test accepted solution with your file `ideone_cny805.java`, is there correct output? And solution without write to csv is create list and in loop append data not to file, but to list. then create dataframe from output list.