# resolve conflict priority using python merge rows

Tags: python, pandas, merge

INPUT

```
>>> data
     OrderID            TimeStamp  ErrorCode Duration          ResponseType  \
0    3000000  1488948188555841641        NaN      IOC                   NaN   
1    3000000  1488948188556444675          0      NaN     NEW_ORDER_CONFIRM   
2    3000000  1488948188556448153          2      NaN         TRADE_CONFIRM
```

OUTPUT EXPECTED

```
>>> data
     OrderID            TimeStamp1           TimeStamp2  ErrorCode Duration       ResponseType     

2    3000000  1488948188555841641  1488948188556448153          0      IOC         TRADE_CONFIRM
```

Basically I want to collapse the 2 rows according to OrderID, but Errorcode, needs to be taken from NEW_ORDER_CONFIRM only.

Larger intent of question is [Use particular column value as key to search in pandas dataframe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42688453/use-particular-column-value-as-key-to-search-in-pandas-dataframe)

Comment: It's the OUTPUT you're showing what you're getting now, or the desired result?

Comment: That is the required output

Comment: Ok, but in your write-up you want to collapse according to OrderID, so I would expect just one row, what is the logic to keep two rows?

Comment: ohh yes.. I made a mistake it should be just 1. Updated :)

Comment: Doesn't look like you're giving us all the logic required here.  It looks like you're looking for:

```1. A unique OrderID
2. TimeStamp where Duration = 'IOC'
3. ErrorCode where ResponseType = 'NEW_ORDER_CONFIRM'
4. ResponseType always = 'TRADE_CONFIRM'.```

Is that correct?

Comment: @pshep123 Almost exactly the same what your have mentioned. Just that ResponseType can either be `TRADE_CONFIRM` or `CANCEL_ORDER_CONFIRM` I would then group by ErrorCode how many got `TRADE_CONFIRM` and how many got `CANCEL_ORDER_CONFIRM`